# Возможно ли настроить роутер как свитч для OpenVPN-сети?

Tags: сеть, администрирование, маршрутизация, openvpn

Есть готовый OpenVPN сервер с выделенным внешним ip. И есть роутер Mikrotik rb951g-2hnd, который умеет сам быть OpenVPN сервером и клиентом, он обслуживает локальную сеть. Можно ли настроить этот роутер так, чтобы его DHCP давал адреса в той же подсети, что и OpenVPN и что бы другие клиенты OpenVPN могли свободно видеть хосты локальной сети, обслуживаемой роутером?

Говоря образно и грубо - возможно ли роутер Mikrotik настроить сетевым коммутатором для OpenVPN?

Возможно ли с помощью OpenVPN  реализовать такую схему? Чтобы не настраивать отдельно каждого клиента виртуальной частной сети, как это бывает обычно, а чтобы маршрутизатор обслуживал часть физических клиентов и все они были в одной с OpenVPN сервером подсети?

Если это все возможно, пожалуйста, подскажите возможную топологию и маршрутизацию для реализации этой задачи.

Comment: Ходят слухи, что openvpn в микротике говно совершенно не юзабельное. А в принципе настроить можно, только это не называют свичом для openvpn. Сначала надо привести в порядок свои знания о компьютерных сетях.

Comment: Вам надо думать не в рамках DHCP-серверов - а в рамках маршрутизации. Нет никакой "сети роутера", есть просто локальная сеть. И есть виртуальная сеть OpenVPN. Это - две разные сети, а в разных сетях должны быть разные диапазоны адресов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно:

1. Перевести OpenVPN-сервер в режим tap (в режим канального уровня OSI). Коммутация работает только на канальном уровне.
2. Если сервер находится в локальной сети роутера - то достаточно на сервере сделать мост между виртуальной сетью и реальной. Способ объединения двух сетевых адаптеров в мост ищите в мануалах по вашей ОС.

   Также надо будет просто выключить DHCP на сервере - тогда роутер будет раздавать адреса.
3. Если сервер находится снаружи - то на роутере надо настроить OpenVPN-клиент, после чего на роутере объединить два сетевых интерфейса в мост. Как это сделать - ищите в мануалах по роутеру.

   В этой конфигурации надо будет также выключить DHCP на сервере, чтобы роутер мог раздавать адреса. Или же можно выключить DHCP на роутере, чтобы адреса раздавал сервер.

   Не забудьте также разрешить на сервере клиентам взаимодействовать друг с другом.

Полезная ссылка: https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/miscellaneous/76-ethernet-bridging.html